# How to concatenate two List<string> to a single string using Aggregate method

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have two lists of strings. My manager's requirement is to concatenate both lists and output as a string using LINQ.

```
List<string> upper = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
List<string> lower = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
```

The output should be something as below:
    //string output = "A:a,B:b,C:c"

And to achieve this, I need to use LINQ Aggregate method or other extension methods available. Please help

Comment: What have you tried?  What hasn't worked?  You'll have to post your code

Comment: @Alireza That was a terrible edit, no need for any of the changes you made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the method `Zip` and maybe combined with `string.Join`

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", upper.Zip(lower, (u, l) => u + ":" + l)));
```

This outputs: `A:a,B:b,C:c`

Comment: Thanks @ZarX . It works :) But I did this and woks too.
     string output = upper.Zip(lower, (a, b) => a + ":" + b).ToList().Aggregate((c, d) => c + "," + d);

Comment: @PranabKumarDe : ToList() is not required

Answer (score 1):

You need [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) method not `Aggregate`:

If you want the result as a `List` of `String`:

```
List<string> result = upper.Zip(lower, (first, second) => first + ":" + second).ToList();
```

If you want the result as a string you can either use [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this:

```
string output = string.Join(",", result);
```

Or `Aggregate` method as you are looking for like this:

```
string output = result.Aggregate((f, s) => f + "," + s);
```

Comment: Thanks @S.Akbari .. It worked :) 

    string output = upper.Zip(lower, (a, b) => a + ":" + b).ToList().Aggregate((c, d) => c + "," + d);

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var results = upper.Zip(lower, (up, low) => $"{up}:{low}");
```

Now to convert it into a single string:

```
string output = string.Join(",", results);
```